# Run a task in background and know the time of its termination

Tags: shell-script, php, background-process

I need to run a unix shell script (`my_script`) in background and monitor it from web interface.

I start the actual script from php like so:

```
$command = 'my_script';
$pid= exec("nohup {$command} > {$logFile} & echo $!");
```

Then `$pid` contains the pid of my process and I can find out if the process is still running by checking `file_exists("/proc/{$pid}")`.

However, here's the problem: how do I find out when the process has terminated and how long it ran when it is terminated?

Also, is there a good way to find out when the process has started? I can record the timestamp in PHP before or after I make the `exec` call, but that will be somewhat inaccurate.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, PHP script can't wait for shell script to finish. The shell script needs to be run in the background.
I can probably wrap three commands (record time started, run `my_script`, record time finished) into one shell with `sh -c` pass it to `nohup`, but I would prefer the whole sequence to be atomic, so that I do not end up with only start time recorded if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get rid of the intermediary shell and start it as your direct child, probably with something like `proc_open` (I'm no PHP expert). Then you'll get a `SIGCHLD` when the child terminates. You can install a signal handler for it (`pcntl_signal` most likely) and in it nonblockingly (`WNOHANG`) wait (`pcntl_waitpid` ) on your child's PID and if the wait succeeds, record the time and remove the signal handler.

`file_exists("/proc/{$pid}")` is unreliable if you don't control the `wait` calls (if `pid` isn't your child) because PIDs get recycled.

Comment: Problem is, i _need_ to run that script in the background. So my php script can't wait for that other script to finish.

Comment: I said you should `wait` in you signal handler. Signals are asynchronous.

Comment: `proc_open` won't block your script. Your script will go on and when the child process terminates, your script will get the `SIGCHLD` signal. You need to have a handler for that signal. In it you check whether it was truly the death of your child process by calling it with the target child's  and the `WNOHANG` flag and if it was, you record the time of death and uninstall the handler (SIGCHLD generally means something's up with one of your child processes).

Comment: I trust you'll be able to search the documentation (http://php.net/manual/ ; I believe) for invocation-related details.

Comment: Do I get this correctly: PHP starts `my_script` as its child using `proc_open`, and then continues execution. At some point the child is terminated and this PHP script gets a signal and executes the proper handler. But then this means that PHP script can't stop until its child terminates (even though the waiting is non-blocking and it can do other stuff)?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: But does this mean that PHP script can't stop until its child terminates (even though the waiting is non-blocking and it can do other stuff)?

Comment: Is that a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25040/discussion-between-beowulfenator-and-pskocik).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to call for at/batch since you are using a web front end. The results can either be emailed to the user or a que which gets poled by the user (using client side javascript or just plain user based checking).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to record a script's exit conditions is to make it record them.

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'date +"
    My name is $0. My PID is $$.
    My start time was '"$(date)."'
    The time is now %X on %x.
    My exit code is $?. Goodbye.
"   >/tell/somebody' EXIT
: now do some stuff
```

An EXIT trap should work in every exit scenario but one which is initiated by a **SIGKILL**.

If you cannot edit the script in question just wrap the script in a shell whose instructions you can control - such as with `sh -c` as you mentioned:

```
trap=': the trap' sh -c '
trap "$trap" 0;. "$0"'   \
    ./script/i/cant/edit \
    positional params    &
```

A similar thing might done w/ `sh -s`, but the value of `$0` may not be as simply as controlled. With some shells you need to `exec` a new infile/replacement shell in order to alter it *(I sometimes use symlinks and `PATH=.` w/ `exec` to change/drop all path components in a process name)*.

```
echo 'trap "$trap" EXIT'   |
cat - ./script/i/cant/edit | 
trap=': the trap' sh -s -- \
    positional params go here &
```